# Trying to get accounts that owe for a particular month in my estate management project

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to C# and SQL. I would love to get help on how to get just the accounts of those owing for a particular month. The query should not include those that have paid for that same month and not owing. For instance, for the month of February, James, John and Samuel paid and for the month of March only Samuel paid.

This is the code I wrote, but it is still returning those that are not owing. It still returns Samuel as a debtor despite he is the only one not owing for March.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblPayment 
WHERE NOT (@fmonth > MONTH( DateCreated) 
           AND @fyear > YEAR( DateCreated))
  AND NOT (@tmonth <= MONTH( DateCreated) 
           AND @tyear <= YEAR( DateCreated)) 
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

How do I get just James and John without repeating Samuel? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of people who haven't made a payment, you will need access to a list of potential people who need to pay. In this example below I've assumed you have an accounts receivable table with the names of people who need to pay.

This example uses a correlated subquery and an existence clause to only return names and accounts from the accounts receivable table where that account doesn't have a payment record during the month in question.

In a real application account receivable logic would need to be more complicated because accounts can pay ahead and go negative, but I think this works as a simple example.

```
SELECT AR.name, AR.AccountNumber 
FROM AccountsReceivable AR
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM tblPayment p 
                  WHERE MONTH(DateCreated) = @month 
                    AND YEAR(DateCreated) = @year 
                    AND p.AccountNumber = AR.AccountNumber)
```

It might be possible to get the answer you are looking for by only querying tblPayment, but that makes the assumption that people that haven't paid have a zero value or null entry with their name and you haven't given us enough information in your question to make those assumptions.

Comment: Thanks. I have 2 tables. One takes in the account details. That is the name,address, age and other basic information and then the tblPayment table which holds the payment details of each accounts.

Comment: i just tried your solution. But it still returns the Samuel as a debtor. i would like it to just return James and John and not include Samuel.

Comment: What values are in the row for Samuel and what values are you using for @month and @year?

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Assuming you have the accounts in one table and the payments in another (tblPayment) you could select only the account Ids that are not present in the payments table for a particular month (in this example, for March) by applying the following query (sample data are in array of objects but the query can be applied to database tables, as is):

```
var accounts = new [] {
    new { Id=1, Name="James" },
    new { Id=2, Name="John" },
    new { Id=3, Name="Samuel" }
};

var tblPayment = new [] {
    new { Month=2, AccountId=1 },
    new { Month=2, AccountId=2 },
    new { Month=2, AccountId=3 },
    new { Month=3, AccountId=3 }
};

// James and John for March - Empty for February
var debtors_march = accounts
                    .Where(a => !tblPayment.Where(p => p.Month == 3)
                    .Any(p => p.AccountId == a.Id));
```